# How to get audio in decibels

Tags: python, audio

I'm writing a script that will automatically adjust the audio levels of a program, So I need a way to get audio levels in python. I've looked online for libs to help with this but I was unable to find anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the system output volume in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662850/how-do-i-get-the-system-output-volume-in-python)

Comment: no, i need the volume in dB

Comment: well that's going to depend on what speakers you have, so do a conversion based on the system output volume and the speaker power

Comment: what libs or resources should i use for that

Comment: you could use your microphone to listen to the output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082635/accessing-the-microphone-in-python or check the specs of your setup and see if theres any info

Comment: surely there's a lib for getting speaker audio levels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246860/discussion-between-shotgunflamez-and-hugh-mungus).